# What is the fundamental difference between multipartite and multilevel secret sharing?

Tags: secret-sharing, terminology

According to this [paper](http://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/440d/fa8ab99301d4ea3a8b19c0748575915aef15.pdf) ,
**Multipartite secret sharing scheme** is a scheme in which the set of participants is divided into disjoint parts and all participants in the same part play an equivalent role in the scheme.

I am not sure about the exact and formal  definition for Multilevel secret sharing scheme.

What is the fundamental difference between multipartite and multilevel secret sharing scheme?